# matplotlib show incomplete tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need use Matplotlib to draw headmaps with chinese tick labels. But the result shows incomplete tick labels as below. I don't know why it happened. I tried to change other chinese font but doesn't work. How to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import mpl
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['STZhongsong']    
mpl.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = True          

def heatmap(data, row_labels, col_labels, ax=None,
            cbar_kw={}, cbarlabel="", **kwargs):

    if not ax:
        ax = plt.gca()

    im = ax.imshow(data, **kwargs)

    cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax, **cbar_kw)
    cbar.ax.set_ylabel(cbarlabel, rotation=-90, va="bottom")

    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]))

    ax.set_xticklabels(col_labels)
    ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels)

    ax.tick_params(top=True, bottom=False,
                   labeltop=True, labelbottom=False)

    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=-20, ha="right",
             rotation_mode="anchor")

    for edge, spine in ax.spines.items():
        spine.set_visible(False)

    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]+1)-.5, minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]+1)-.5, minor=True)
    ax.grid(which="minor", color="w", linestyle='-', linewidth=3)
    ax.tick_params(which="minor", bottom=False, left=False)

    return im, cbar

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x,y = list("你这是干什么啦？"),list("你要吃什么？")
    s = np.random.random([len(x), len(y)])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    im, cbar = heatmap(s, x, y, ax=ax,
                       cmap="YlGn", cbarlabel="attention scores")

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("test", dpi=300, bbox_inches = 'tight')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: try  `ax.autofmt_xdate()` after setting ```ax.set_xticklabels(col_labels)
    ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels)```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as mfm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def heatmap(data, row_labels, col_labels, ax=None,
            cbar_kw={}, cbarlabel="", **kwargs):

    if not ax:
        ax = plt.gca()

    im = ax.imshow(data, **kwargs)

    cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax, **cbar_kw)
    cbar.ax.set_ylabel(cbarlabel, rotation=-90, va="bottom")

    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]))
    font_path = "/Downloads/ZCOOLXiaoWei-Regular.ttf"
    prop = mfm.FontProperties(fname=font_path)
   
    ax.set_xticklabels(col_labels,fontproperties=prop,fontsize=50)
    ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels,fontproperties=prop,fontsize=50)
   

    ax.tick_params(top=True, bottom=False,
                   labeltop=True, labelbottom=False)

    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=-20, ha="right",
             rotation_mode="anchor")

    for edge, spine in ax.spines.items():
        spine.set_visible(False)

    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]+1)-.5, minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]+1)-.5, minor=True)
    ax.grid(which="minor", color="w", linestyle='-', linewidth=3)
    ax.tick_params(which="minor", bottom=False, left=False)

    return im, cbar

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x,y = list("你这是干什么啦"),list("你这是干什么啦")
    s = np.random.random([len(x), len(y)])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

    im, cbar = heatmap(s, x, y, ax=ax,
                       cmap="YlGn", cbarlabel="attention scores")

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("test", dpi=300, bbox_inches = 'tight')
    plt.show()
```

I have made few changes in the code and used the matplotlib.font_manager to render the Chinese font.[image]

Comment: it seems problem still exists if the label has punctuation inside. eg. x,y = list("你这是干什么啦?"),list("你要吃什么?")

Comment: yes, punctuation and English alphabet also cause the issue